# unable to open visual studio code

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

[image]

Visual studio code fails to open with the error `failed to open v8 file natives_blob.bin`. In the said path, there is no such file found. Tried to reinstall but still the same error

Comment: Yeah this looks like a botched installation, have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: Thank you. Tried multiple ways to fix with no success. Reinstalled and it created a new file and works fine. It was working fine until yesterday. Not sure how the file went missing suddenly though

Comment: Got to know from a few others that it happened to them too after installing OS update. The file went missing and they had to reinstall it to make it work.